# Error in showing JavaScript output to screen with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JavaScript, and wrote this fairly simple quiz game. It asks the user for answers to the game and then evaluates their responses. I have a 2-D array for storing the questions along with the answers. The logic is all clear.

Things were working fine with the `document.write()` method. But once I decided to put the results dynamically in a `div` in the HTML, that's where it all blew up. The game cycles through the questions and records the answers, but there's no display on screen.

I ensured the `<script>` is at the end of the HTML file, just above `</body>`, so that it runs only after the `DOM` is loaded. But that didn't make any difference. I'm sure it's a very small issue, I just can't put my finger on it, yet.

Here's the JS code:

```
var questions = [

    ["Which city has the largest population?", "tokyo"],
    ["What are the small indentations on a golf ball called?", "dimples"],
    ["What is Tiger Woods's first name?", "eldrick"],
    ["In which war was Operation Desert Storm conducted?", "gulf war"],
    ["Which country is bordered by both the Indian and Atlantic Oceans?", "republic of south africa"],
    ["How many men have walked on the moon?", "12"],
    ["Which is the most common human blood type?", "O"]

];

var correctQuestions = [];
var incorrectQuestions = [];

var correct = 0;
var incorrect = 0;


//logic for the game
function quiz(questions) {
    var numOfQuestions = questions.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfQuestions; i++) {

        //display question and record answer
        var response = prompt(questions[i][0]);
        response = response.toLowerCase();
        if (response === questions[i][1]) {

            correct += 1;
            correctQuestions.push(questions[i]);
        } else {
            incorrect += 1;
            incorrectQuestions.push(questions[i]);
        }

    }
}


//show list of questions
function displayResult(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var show = "<li>" + arr[i][0] + "</li>";
        print(show);
    }
}

function print(message) {

    var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
    outputDiv.innerHTML = message;

}



quiz(questions);

var output1 = "<h1>Thank You for taking the quiz!</h1>";

output1 += "<h2>You got " + correct + " questions correct:</h2>";

output1 += "<ol>";

print(output1);

displayResult(correctQuestions);

var output2 = "</ol>";

output2 += "<h2>You got " + incorrect + " questions wrong:</h2>";
output2 += "<ol>";

print(output2);
displayResult(incorrectQuestions);

print("</ol>");
```

The complete code, along with the HTML and CSS is on [this JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/manishgiri/8c4qq11z/). Even here, I selected the `onDomready`, just to ensure it's not the "writing to a non-existent div" problem, but that didn't make any difference either.

Comment: Just curious. What caused the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your `print` function needs updated.

```
function print(message) {
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
    outputDiv.innerHTML += message; // <---- needs to be '+=' to append the message

}
```

Comment: The OP is also appending LI elements to a DIV via markup, which is invalid and will trigger browser error correction (which might do anything).

Comment: Works fine in JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8c4qq11z/1/. I also updated the code to be a bit cleaner to read.

Comment: Yep. Adding invalid markup to innerHTML means that browsers revert to error correction, which they are pretty good at and generally do something useful, but it's not healthy as a general strategy and may mean different browsers give different results.